# remote attribute does not allow to post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, post, data-annotations, jsonresult

I'm trying to check if TerminalID already is taken by another model. The Ajax is posting back correctly and error message also can be seen, but the page will not allow me to submit , I only need to check this information while input to display error message and then post anyway . help me please

Model :

```
public class MoveModel
{
    [Required]
    [Remote("CheckExistTrm", "MoveModel")]
    public int TerminalID { get; set; }

    public string User { get; set; }
    ........
}
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult CheckExistTrm(int TerminalID)
    {
        var terminal = db.Terminals.Find(TerminalID);
        if (terminal == null)
            return null;
        var agrdet = (from t in db.AgreementDetails where (t.TerminalID == terminal.TerminalID && t.Condition == "New") select t).FirstOrDefault();
        if (agrdet != null)
        {
            var agreement = db.Agreements.Find(agrdet.AgreementID);
            return Json("consider! this terminal is active in the agreement: " + agreement.AgreementNumber ,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);     
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

View (I am using devexpress ):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateAndEdit", "MoveModel", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "edit_form" })){

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.Hidden("MoveModelID")
<div class="line">
    @Html.DevExpress().Label(
        settings =>
        {
            settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "label";
            settings.AssociatedControlName = "TerminalID";
            settings.Text = "ტემრინალი";
        }
    ).GetHtml()
    @Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(
                settings =>
                {
                    settings.Name = "TerminalID";
                    settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "editor";
                    settings.Properties.TextField = "Name";
                    settings.Properties.ValueField = "TerminalID";
                    settings.Properties.ValueType = typeof(int);
                    settings.Properties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDown;
                    settings.Properties.IncrementalFilteringMode = IncrementalFilteringMode.Contains;
                }
            ).BindList(LeaseReg.Models.Terminal.getTerminals()).Bind(Model.TerminalID).GetHtml()
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TerminalID,null, new { @class = "validator" })
</div>

<div class="line">
    @Html.DevExpress().Label(
        settings =>
        {
            settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "label";
        }
    ).GetHtml()
    @Html.DevExpress().Button(
        settings =>
        {
            settings.Name = "btnUpdate";
            settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
            settings.Text = "დადასტურება";
            settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
        }
    ).GetHtml()
    @Html.DevExpress().Button(
        settings =>
        {
            settings.Name = "btnCancel";
            settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button"; ;
            settings.Text = "გაუქმება";
            settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e){ document.location='" + DevExpressHelper.GetUrl(new { Controller = "MoveModel", Action = "Index" }) + "'; }";
        }
        ).GetHtml()

</div>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true);}
```

Comment: If you have a validation error, then the form will not submit - thats the whole point of using the validation scripts. If your just wanting to return an 'information' message, the remove the `[Remote]` attribute and just make an ajax call in the `.blur()` event.

Comment: Yes , but is there any way to ignore this error ?

Comment: No. Its a validation error and that's what its designed to do. Just delete you attribute and make your own ajax call to return the message and display it in the view (then its just information for the user, not a validation error)

Comment: Okay , got it  , Thanks